# git rebase --continue: how to suppress the "no changes" check

Tags: git

Is there a way to configure `git` so that `git rebase --continue` skips the "no changes" test?

I don't want `git rebase --continue` to ever fail because it detects no changes.  It should automatically delete the commit when this happens.

**Why?**

I frequently run into the problem with git where I `git rebase --continue` fails because it sees no changes and requires me to say `git rebase --skip`.  I understand why this happens, but it slows down my workflow and makes it more dangerous: if I'm doing a large rebase where the problem recurs multiple times, along with legitimate merge conflicts, I'm more likely to accidentally use a skip command from the history when I meant to reuse a continue command.

**Example**

Suppose I have the following history:

```
A -- B -- C -- D -- E -- F    <-- topic
 \
   H -- I                     <-- master
```

and I want to push commits B, C, E, and F to the master branch in `origin`.

Suppose that when I cherry pick them, B works fine, C and F have some trivial merge conflict caused by commits H and I, and E has a non-trivial merge conflict that needs to be resolved differently if H and I are in the history than if D is in the history.  After resolving those conflicts, suppose my history is:

```
A -- B -- C -- D -- E -- F    <-- topic
 \
   H -- I -- B -- C' -- E'' -- F'  <-- master
```

Now, I want to rebase my `topic` branch onto `master`.  In doing so, B will get automatically dropped, but I'll get merge conflicts for C, E, and F because they were modified when they were cherry-picked.  When the rebase pauses at C, resolving the conflicts results in no net change, so `git` will be defensive and complain when I try to run `git rebase --continue`:

```
No changes - did you forget to use 'git add'?
```

The solution is to use `git rebase --skip` instead.  At that point, E will conflict; resolving it requires actual changes, so I actually (and successfully) use `git rebase --continue`.  Then, F produces another spurious merge conflict.  As with C, resolving that conflict results in no net changes, so again I'm told to use skip mode when I try to continue.

I'd like to configure `git` so that when I resolve a merge conflict (esp. with `mergetool`) and the resolution results in no net changes, I want `git rebase --continue` to just do the work of `git rebase --skip`, at most prompting me.  I'd prefer it always auto-skip if it can't be smart enough to know that I ran the mergetool.  The continue option seems to be defending against incorrect `git checkout` commands mid-rebase; I'm familiar enough with git these days to never be in danger of accidentally nuking changes mid-rebase.  I have however come close to accidentally doing a skip when my history looks like this:

```
 git rebase            # start the rebase
 git mergetool         # apply non-trivial fix
 git rebase --continue # succeeds: non-trivial fix
 git mergetool         # apply non-trivial fix
 git rebase --continue # succeeds: non-trivial fix
 git mergetool         # apply non-trivial fix
 git rebase --continue # succeeds: non-trivial fix
 git mergetool         # nuke all changes from the topic branch
 git rebase --continue # fails: no changes
 git rebase --skip     # this should have been automatic
 git mergetool         # apply non-trivial fix (THIS MUST NOT BE SKIPPED)
 ... here I have to be careful and not just reflexively hit up-arrow twice then <ENTER>...
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Interesting question. Here [Automatically skip empty commits when using git rebase](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11127771/automatically-skip-empty-commits-when-using-git-rebase) user Olivier Refalo suggested using a function from G2, simplified git interface for newbies. Basically it boils down to checking whether contents of files in index is different from files the repository after doing `git add`. If it's different do `git rebase --continue`, if it's the same do `git rebase --skip`. You could create script that would do the following:

```
#!/bin/sh

if git diff-index --quiet HEAD --; then
    git rebase --skip
else
    git rebase --continue
fi
```

Alternatively you can add an alias to your .gitconfig:

```
[alias]
          reb = "!if git diff-index --quiet HEAD --; then git rebase --skip; else git rebase --continue; fi"
```